# sql server - check to see if cast is possible then use in order clauses

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a varchar(20) column, need to convert to int and use in order clauses. But things is okay when it is possible to convert. My code:

```
            SELECT    DISTINCT people.ParYear,CAST(people.ParID As int), people.Pfamily, people.Pname
            FROM               people 
            WHERE            people.osID    = @osID 
                         AND people.shID    = @shID
                         AND people.ParYear = @ParYear
               ORDER BY        people.ParYear, CAST(people.ParID As int)
```

So how can I avoid error Message like Conversion failed!

sample data:

|**osID**|**shID**|**ParYear**|**ParID**|**Pfamily**|**Pname**|
|------|-------|-----------|--------|---------|-----------|
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 5       | A        |A1           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 8-1    | AB      |A2           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 7       | AC      |A3           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 4       | ACD   |A4           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 1       | AD      |A5           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 6       | AF      |A6           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 3       | AFF    |A7           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 2      | AG     |A8           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 12*3  | AN     |A9           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 9- 4   | AI      |A0           |
|     4| 12    | 2016     | 178/2   | AS      |A00          |
|-----|--------|-----------|--------|---------|-----------|

Need to order:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8-1
9- 4
12*3
178/2

Comment: Depending on which version you're running, you might have access to try_cast for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx

Comment: Thank you for replay. I using sql server 2005

Comment: why you want to cast during order by clause? order-by without cast will get the intended results.. is it not?

Comment: Not necessarily. Consider values 1, 20 and 100 f.ex.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy Not always, if the field is a varchar than 11 will be before 2, converting it to int will make 2 before 11.

Comment: no it doesn't make desired output. it will look something like 2016-1, 2016-10, 2016-11, 2016-2. I have to use order-by.

Comment: @user81594: '2016-1'  is not directly convertable or castable to int, nor are the other examples. You probably need to include more details as to the contents of the ParID column for a solution to be found.

Comment: can you provide sample data for parID

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see of doing this for older SQL Servers (2005 as in question, newer versions have better/other tools), would be to do a check against the incomming value using something like PATINDEX:

Consider:

```
DECLARE @asVarchar VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @asVarchar2 VARCHAR(200);
SET @asVarchar = '1*2';
SET @asVarchar2 = '12';
DECLARE @asInt INT

IF (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @asVarchar) = 0) BEGIN
    SET @asInt = CAST(@asVarchar AS INT)
END
SELECT @asInt, @asVarchar     -- returns: null, '1*2'

IF (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @asVarchar2) = 0) BEGIN
    SET @asInt = CAST(@asVarchar2 AS INT)
END
SELECT @asInt, @asVarchar     -- returns: 12, '12'
```

Using `PATINDEX` we test if the content of the string(s) `@asVarchar` and `@asVarchar2` contains something other than `0-9` and if it does not - we cast it to int into `@asInt`

So in my example `'1*2'` contains `*` and cannot be converted, so `@asInt` is `NULL`.
But `'12'` only contains 0-9 and therefore we can convert it and `@asInt` becomes `12`.

However, it's not going to be "pretty" and performance might be an issue in complex data, so it might be worth it to reconsider the entire approach and whether or not the underlying problem might be solvable differently by a different approach.

EDIT:
Given your update of sample data, I would think something along this line of thinking might be what you're after:

```
DECLARE @t AS TABLE (sortCol varchar(200))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('178/2')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('12*3')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('9- 4')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('8-1')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('2')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('3')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('4')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('5')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('6')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('7')

SELECT *
FROM @t
ORDER BY 
 CAST(SUBSTRING(sortCol, 1, 
               CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', sortCol) = 0 THEN LEN(sortCol) 
               ELSE  PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', sortCol) - 1 END
     ) AS INT)
```

Comment: You mean: IF (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',(SELECT dbo.people.ParID FROM dbo.people)) = 0)

Comment: You will properly have to go with CASE in the ORDER BY in case the query in your question is complete. However, looking at your update, I think you'll need additional logic for your order by, because you've introduced more rules. You properly need to introduce a specific sort key column if you want to control order by as dynamically as you seem to.

Answer (score -2):

Use `convert` for type casting.

```
SELECT DISTINCT people.ParYear,CAST(people.ParID As int), people.Pfamily,
people.Pname FROM people
WHERE people.osID = @osID
AND people.shID = @shID
AND people.ParYear = @ParYear
ORDER BY people.ParYear, CONVERT(INT,people.ParID)
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I have input like 1*2 or 178/1 or 3-5 or 3  - 5. no control on input.

Comment: so you want result of that expressions?

Comment: How would using CONVERT in stead of CAST help here?